# How to: Create a DockPanel in C# (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, dockpanel

How to: Create a DockPanel in C# (WPF)

I am trying to create a `DockPanel`. The `DockPanel` looks fine so far. The only problem is, that it does not fit like I want it to - please see the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I want "Administration" to be as high (Height) as its content and let's say there are 10 elements in the `DataGrid` (white area below). Now I want it to be fixed in the bottom left corner. Now, when I make the window larger, I want "Geschäftskontakte" to fill the rest free area that is left. Therefore, I do have to following:

```
<!-- Left / Right -->
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="dockPanelModule" Width="150">
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Geschäftskontakte" Name="labelModule">
        </Label>
        <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="dataGridNavigation" Height="200" HeadersVisibility="None">
            <!-- ... -->
        </DataGrid>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Administration" Name="labelAdministration">
        </Label>
        <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="dataGridAdministration" HeadersVisibility="None">
            <!-- ... -->
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
```

I have removed unimportant information like `Background`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You have them in the wrong order.  Move 'Company contact' to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WPF DockPanel doesn't have a Dock.Fill option, but it does have a [LastChildFillProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is true by default), so you'd need to add the element you want to grow to Fill the space last. With all of your items set to DockPanel.Dock=Top, this would put the items out of order, but by grouping the controls with panels, and specifying DockPanel.Dock=Bottom for the bottom group, you can get the desired result:

```
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="dockPanelModule" Width="150" >

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Label Content="Administration" Name="labelAdministration">
            </Label>
            <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="dataGridAdministration" HeadersVisibility="None" MinHeight="30" >
            </DataGrid>

        </StackPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Geschäftskontakte" Name="labelModule">
            </Label>
            <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="dataGridNavigation"  HeadersVisibility="None" MinHeight="75">
                <!-- ... -->
            </DataGrid>

        </DockPanel>                
    </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The order that children are added to the `DockPanel` is important.

From [the MSDN DockPanel documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx):

> Note: The position of child elements of a DockPanel on the screen is
>   determined by the Dock property of the respective child elements and
>   the relative order of those child elements under the DockPanel.
>   Therefore, a set of child elements with the same Dock property values
>   can be positioned differently on the screen depending on the order of
>   these children under the DockPanel. Child ordering effects positioning
>   because the DockPanel iterates through its child elements in order,
>   setting the position of each element depending on remaining space.